# How to use FFImageLoading's FFImage in uwp project

Tags: xaml, uwp, ffimageloading

I download `Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms` in Nuget, the discription says it support uwp. I followed `FFImageLoading/samples/Simple.WinUniversal.Sample/`, and in MainPage.xaml, refered

```
xmlns:ff="using:FFImageLoading"
xmlns:fft="using:FFImageLoading.Transformations"
```

I want to use `FFImage`, so

```
        <ff:FFImage Name="Image"
                Grid.Row="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                TransformPlaceholders="False"
                LoadingPlaceholder="loading.png"
                ErrorPlaceholder="error.png"
                CacheDuration="30"
                RetryCount="3"
                RetryDelay="250"
                Height="500"
                Width="500"
                DownsampleToViewSize="True"
                DownsampleMode="None"
                Source="http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">

    </ff:FFImage>
```

But the designer shows

```
Unknown type 'FFImage' in XML namespace 'using:FFImageLoading'
```

So, what's the correct way to use `FFImage`. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to use FFImageLoading's FFImage in uwp project

Please check this [line](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/source/FFImageLoading.Forms.WinUWP/CachedImageRenderer.cs#L40), it is [Xamarin.Froms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/) control, it could not be used in native uwp project.

For uwp platform we suggest use [ImageEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.imageex?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) to replace that one. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/imageex) .

```
<controls:ImageEx x:Name="ImageExControl1"
     IsCacheEnabled="True"
     Source="/Assets/Photos/LunchBreak.jpg"
     PlaceholderSource="/Assets/Photos/ImageExPlaceholder.jpg"
     Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
```

Comment: For some reason, like a home page designed liked NetFlix, `ImageEx` will causes a huge memory usage when navigating back, while set home page `NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required/Enabled;`.

Comment: If the bug is exist, please report it at Microsoft Community Tool kit source. thx.